# Trying to graph $x^{\frac12} + y^{\frac12} =1$

Tags: calculus

I am a bit rusty with math and I am not sure what the steps would be to graph the function  $x^{\frac12} + y^{\frac12} =1$. I tried doing implicit differentiation but then I wasn't sure where to go from there. Maybe I'm using the wrong approach.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: maybe try in parametric $(\cos(t)^4,\sin(t)^4)$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx-2*Sqrt%5Bx%5D+%2B+1%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C5%7D%5D)

Comment: The correct curve is shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bx-2*Sqrt%5Bx%5D+%2B+1%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D). Both $x$ and $y$ should vary between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $y$ we see that $y^{1/2}=1-x^{1/2}$ and so squaring both sides see that $y=(1-x^{1/2})^2 = 1 -2 x^{1/2} + x$.

Comment: Note that $x$ cannot be larger than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's always nice to restrict the domain and range for implicit equations. If you're graphing this in the real numbers, than you know that neither x nor y can be negative, but they can be zero.

$0 \leq x,y $

Additionally, since the square root of x or y can be both positive and negative, we can restrict the domain and range based on each possibility:

sign$(\sqrt{x}) = $ sign$(\sqrt{y}) = 1\;|\;0 < x,y < 1$
sign$(\sqrt{x}) = $ sign$(\sqrt{y}) = -1\;|\;$Impossible
sign$(\sqrt{x}) = 1$ , sign$(\sqrt{y}) = -1\;|\;1<x$
sign$(\sqrt{x}) = -1$ , sign$(\sqrt{y}) = 1\;|\;1<y$
$x = 0\;|\;y = 1$
$y = 0\;|\;x = 1$

After this exercise, we should algebraically manipulate the original equation into an explicit equation.

$\pm\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}=1$
$\pm\sqrt{y}=1\pm\sqrt{x}$
$y=(1\pm\sqrt{x})^2$

This can be split into four functions:

$y=(1+\sqrt{x})^2\;|\;0\leq\sqrt{y}$
$y=(1+\sqrt{x})^2\;|\;0\geq\sqrt{y}$
$y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2\;|\;0\leq\sqrt{y}$
$y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2\;|\;0\geq\sqrt{y}$

Since the actual equations don't depend on sign$(\sqrt{y})$, then we can further condense this into two equations:
$y=(1+\sqrt{x})^2$
$y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2$

TADA! We have a system of two explicit functions that graph the original implicit equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x,y\in [0,1]$, restricting curve in the first quadrant with the two endpoints $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Another reference point would be $x=y= \frac1{4}$. These three special points would help sketch the curve, symmetric around $y=x$,
[image]